# AAD Converged Apps and Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-account

The documentation for the AAD v2 endpoint here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations mentions the restrictions on services and APIs.  It also says "More Microsoft Online Services will be added in the future, in addition to support for your own custom-built Web APIs and services."

Is there any information on when support for the Azure Resource Manager service will be added?  If not, is there any way for an application to authenticate users with both AAD and MSA accounts and access the Azure Resource Manager service on behalf of the user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to authenticate for the MSA account for the Azure Resource Manager using the Azure AD orignal endpoint, you can add the specific MSA account to the Azure AD tenant which associate with the Azure subscription.

After that you should able to access the Azure Resource Manager service on behalf of the user for the MSA accounts.

Comment: Is there a way to do that programmatically?  Or does this mean I need to know ahead of time the users that have MSA accounts and to white list them?

Comment: Yes, we need to invite the users who you want to access the Azure ResourceManager service before they login. And to achieve this programmatically, we can using the [Microsoft Graph - Create invitation REST](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post) to invite the external users. Then using the [Create a Role Assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest#create-a-role-assignment) to assign the specific role for operating the Azure Resource Manager.

Comment: @DinoViehland The Azure AD V1 endpoint doesn't support to sign-in with the MSA account unless we add it as the external users.

Comment: And that's the reason why I'm using the v2 endpoint and was initially asking if/when additional services will be added including ARM